# appcompat-v7:27.1.1 conflicts with firebase-ads:15.0.1

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, implementation

I am working on a new app. Presently I am trying to add dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
```

**Before** insert row #38:

[image]

**After** insert row #38:

[image]

Any ideas how to best resolve this issue?

*P.S. classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'*

Comment: try to add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0' with ads too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of your dependencies is internally using an older support library version. The best solution is to force it to use a newer one, just add this to dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to resolve this by adding:

`implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'`

You are receiving this error because the library you added has implemented an older version internally.

There is a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/8560690)